# making a copy of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to make a copy of a numpy array in python.
I would then like to change some values of the new array, however somehow this also changes the original?

Why is the following code not correct?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,1])
print("Array a:",a)

b = a
b[0] = a[0]*2
print("Array b after manipulation:", b)

print("Array a, after manipulating array b", a)
```

The only way I can make it work is by list comprehensions.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,1])
print("Array a:",a)

b = [x for x in a]
b[0] = a[0]*2
print("Array b after manipulation:", b)

print("Array a, after manipulating array b", a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, you need to use `copy()`:

```
b = a.copy()
```

Comment: Thank you for the (quick!) answer. Do you have an explanation to why? I believe the first solution is very intuitive. Is it because I use the numpy array instead of a list?

Comment: It only works at first level, it doesn't work if you copy an array of arrays.